# Atualizar registro na tabela usando selected no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou com esse problema, que nao estou conseguindo resolver.

Tenho as seguintes tabelas no banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no formulario ele puxa os dados certinhos, so que na agora que eu vou atualizar por exemplo só a placa e nao altero mais nada no formulario, o campo tipo de veiculos e Setor ele não grava no banco de dados, deixa os dois campos vazio. sendo que eu nao alterei nada nesses dois campos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

so que depois que atualiza ele nao aparece nada nas duas colunas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

formulario php
AtualizarVeiculos.php

```
 <form class="row" name="formcontato" action="UpdateVeiculos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self">

              <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h5 class="box-title"><i class="ion-android-car"></i> - <label>Identificação do Veiculo</label></h5>
                <div class="tile-footer">
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            $idVeiculo = $_GET['idVeiculo']; 
            $result_usuario = "SELECT idVeiculo, placa, prefixo, b.tipoveiculo, c.nomesetor FROM veiculos a INNER JOIN tipoveiculos b on (a.idTipo=b.idTipo) INNER JOIN setores c on (a.idSetor=c.idSetor) WHERE idVeiculo = '$idVeiculo'";
            $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario); $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario); ?>

             <input type="hidden" name="idVeiculo" class="form-control" readonly value="<?php echo $row_usuario['idVeiculo']; ?>" id="idVeiculo" />





              <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Placa</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="placa" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['placa']; ?>" id="placa" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

              <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Prefixo</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="prefixo" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['prefixo']; ?>" id="prefixo" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Marca</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="marca" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['marca']; ?>" id="marca" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Modelo</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="modelo" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['modelo']; ?>" id="modelo" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Ano Fabricação</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="anofab" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['anofab']; ?>" id="anofab" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

              <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Ano Modelo</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="anomodelo" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['anomodelo']; ?>" id="anomodelo" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Numero de Chassis</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="chassis" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['chassis']; ?>" id="chassis" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Numero de Motor</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="motor" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['motor']; ?>" id="motor" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Numero do Renavam</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" name="renavam" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['renavam']; ?>" id="renavam" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Tipo de Veiculos</label></b>
              <select name="idTipo" class="form-control select2" id="idTipo" style="width:100%;" >
              <option selected = "selected" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['idTipo'] ?>" ><?php echo $row_usuario['tipoveiculo'] ?></option>
      <?php
      $resultipo = "SELECT * FROM tipoveiculos";
      $resultadotipo = mysqli_query($conn, $resultipo);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadotipo)) {          
      ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row['idTipo']; ?>"><?php echo $row['tipoveiculo']; ?></option>
                <?php
      }
      ?>
               </select>
          </div>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Setor</label></b>
              <select name="idSetor" class="form-control select2" id="idSetor" style="width:100%;" >
              <option selected = "selected" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['idSetor'] ?>" ><?php echo $row_usuario['nomesetor'] ?></option>
      <?php
      $resultipo = "SELECT * FROM setores";
      $resultadotipo = mysqli_query($conn, $resultipo);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadotipo)) {          
      ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row['idSetor']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nomesetor']; ?></option>
                <?php
      }
      ?>
               </select>
          </div>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Tipo de Eixo</label></b>
              <select name="eixo" class="form-control select2" id="eixo" style="width:100%;" >
              <option selected = "selected" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['eixo'] ?>" ><?php echo $row_usuario['eixo'] ?></option>
              <option value="TOCO">TOCO</option>
              <option value="TRUCADO">TRUCADO</option>
               </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h5 class="box-title"><i class="fa ion-ios-speedometer"></i> - <label>Horimetro - Revisão - Troca de Oleo e Filtros</label></h5>
                <div class="tile-footer">
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>


        <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Revisão</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="insira horimetro" name="revisao" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['revisao']; ?>" id="revisao" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Oleo Motor</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="insira horimetro" name="oleomotor" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['oleomotor']; ?>" id="oleomotor" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Oleo Cambio</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="insira horimetro" name="oleocambio" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['oleocambio']; ?>" id="oleocambio" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Oleo Diferencial</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="insira horimetro" name="oleodiferencial" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['oleodiferencial']; ?>" id="oleodiferencial" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Filtro Hidraulico</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="insira horimetro" name="filtrohidraulico" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['filtrohidraulico']; ?>" id="filtrohidraulico" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <b><label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Filtro AL-12</label></b>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="insira horimetro" name="filtroal12" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['filtroal12']; ?>" id="filtroal12" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-1">
          <div class="form-group">

               <input type="hidden"  name="dataalteracao"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>" class="form-control" id="datacadastro" />
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
        <div class="tile-footer">
          <button  type="submit" onclick="return validar_form_contato()" class="ion-compose btn btn-primary pull-right" > Atualizar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

            </form>
```

UpdateVeiculos.php

```
 $id         =     $_POST['idVeiculo'];
  $placa      =     $_POST['placa'];
  $prefixo    =     $_POST['prefixo'];
  $marca      =     $_POST['marca'];
  $modelo     =     $_POST['modelo'];
  $anofab     =     $_POST['anofab'];
  $anomodelo  =     $_POST['anomodelo'];
  $chassis    =     $_POST['chassis'];
  $motor      =     $_POST['motor'];
  $renavam    =     $_POST['renavam'];
  $idTipo     =     $_POST['idTipo'];
  $idsetor    =     $_POST['idSetor'];
  $eixos       =     $_POST['eixo'];
  $revisao    =     $_POST['revisao'];
  $oleomotor  =     $_POST['oleomotor'];
  $oleocambio =     $_POST['oleocambio'];
  $oleodif    =     $_POST['oleodiferencial'];
  $filtrohid  =     $_POST['filtrohidraulico'];
  $filtroal12 =     $_POST['filtroal12'];
  $usuarioalt =     $_POST['usuarioalteracao'];
  $dataalt    =     $_POST['dataalteracao'];









  $query  = "UPDATE veiculos SET placa = '$placa', prefixo = '$prefixo', marca = '$marca', anofab = '$anofab', anomodelo = '$anomodelo', chassis = '$chassis', motor = '$motor', renavam = '$renavam', idTipo = '$idTipo', idSetor = '$idsetor', eixo = '$eixos' WHERE idVeiculo = '$id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você está fazendo a consulta dos dados do usuário não está retornando os campos de ID:

```
"SELECT idVeiculo, placa, prefixo, b.tipoveiculo, c.nomesetor FROM ..."
```

Adicione os campos `a.idTipo` e `a.idSetor`

Ative a exibição de erros, esses erros são facilmente pegos com os erros ativados.

Outro ponto é que seu código está vulnerável a SQL Injection. Só utilizar `mysqli` não deixará seu código mais seguro, deve utilizar *prepared statements*.

Comment: certo obrigado pela a dica do SQL Injection, entao o que voce pediu para inserir o a.idTipo e a.idSetor eu inseri 

    SELECT idVeiculo, placa, prefixo, a.idTipo, a.idSetor FROM veiculos a
                  INNER JOIN tipoveiculos b on (a.idTipo=b.idTipo)
                  INNER JOIN setores c on (a.idSetor=c.idSetor)
    WHERE idVeiculo = '$idVeiculo'

so que veja como ficou no formulario 

[link] (https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/resultado1-png-ab83c026-9fbf-4dc6-96a5-3da2d4e46cbf)

nao veio os nomes o que apareceu foi os IDs

Comment: Você não deve remover os campos existentes, apenas adicionar os dois que foram mencionados,

Comment: showww.... deu certo agora!!!, obrigado pela a dedicação... valew